# Built-in Database not storing data in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, offline, built-in

I am developing an application in WPF, i am using built-in (i.e. Database file is stored along the application and not on any SQL Server or other Database) Database for the same. Whenever i am running the application and saving/updating the data in the database, it is only available for that scope.
After closing the application, the data is not saved in the database.

What should be done to prevent the data being lost on application close ??

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Please show the code u use to save the data

Comment: We would definitely need a lot more information. The saving and loading of data is not automatic. You need to handle how your application behaves when it closes.

Comment: using (InvoiceEntities objInv = new InvoiceEntities())

{
 objInv.Companies.AddObject(objCompany); //New object with values
 objInv.SaveChanges(); 
 objInv.AcceptAllChanges();
}